# How to configure Xcode swift 3.0 migration tool? (a.k.a. migrator converter)

Tags: swift, xcode, migration, configure

Migrating my project to swift 3.0 in one bulk, using the Xcode converter, is looking like a OMG task.

The converter requires me solve/save/convert far too many issues at the same time.

Isn't there a way to configure the migration tool to only apply some of the conversion rules, and ditch the others?

I would like to make the conversion incrementally, instead.

Specifically, if I could at least disable the conversion step, where it deals with the new optionals imported from the objc headers, it would already be great help.

This is because I hate the way the converter handles the new optionals that swift 3.0 requires to handle. As it would just add a ton of question marks everywhere, as opposed to a single force unwrap, which I prefer in most cases.

I tried converting first to swift 2.3. But unfortunately the 2.3 specs don't require the same kind of handling of optionals. Because the swift 2.3 still imports objC headers the old way.